# Why does "scaled z ticks" not work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Im creating a whole bunch of 3D plots where I want automatic scaling of the z ticks, i.e. a common exponent should be factored out, like it ought to be the default behaviour in pgfplots. However, as can be seen in the MWE, it just doesn't work. If I specify the exponent manually by setting `scaled z ticks={base 10:{-2}}`, it works. This is not a good solution because there are many plots. It seems liks pgfplots is not able to detect the ranges somehow.

So my question is: why doesn't it work as expected and how do I get it to work?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % this doesnt work
        \matrix{
        \begin{axis}[
            width=5cm,
            height=5cm,
            scaled z ticks = true
        ]
            \addplot3 [
                z buffer=sort,
            ]
            table[point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
                x   y   z   c
                0   0   -796.712    -796.712
                0.966   0.05    -311.152    -311.152
                0.033   0.25    -1230.162   -1230.162
                1   1   -76.631 -76.631
            };
        \end{axis}
        &
        % it should look like this
        \begin{axis}[
            width=5cm,
            height=5cm,
            scaled z ticks={base 10:{-2}}
        ]
            \addplot3 [
                z buffer=sort,
            ]
            table[point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
                x   y   z   c
                0   0   -796.712    -796.712
                0.966   0.05    -311.152    -311.152
                0.033   0.25    -1230.162   -1230.162
                1   1   -76.631 -76.631
            };
        \end{axis}
        \\};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3d plots without and with z tick scaling]

Comment: That's a bit odd. It is clear that `scaled z ticks = true` does not change anything because `true` is the initial value, but of course this does not answer your question.

Comment: Good that you tell the readers. I knew that but wanted to emphasize that it should work normally...